# Extenting a homeomorphism on subsurface to the entire surface

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose you have surface and a subsurface. The complement of subsurface is union of open discs and once punctured open discs. Can all homeomorphisms of the subsurface be extended to homeomorphisms of the surface? There is a way of doing this by assuming the identity on the complement. Is this way unique?

Comment: Hint: Alexander's trick

Comment: By Alexander trick i know that homeomorphism of disc or once punctured disc is isotopic to identity. Is this says to me the only way of extention by identity? It is not clear for me.

Comment: another way to see it, is that any homeomorphism in the border can be extended to the disk

Comment: Does a closed annulus count as a subsurface of a disk?  Because you can swap the boundaries of a closed annulus via homeomorphism...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:  **No, you cannot extend all homeomorphisms to the entire surface**.

For a counterexample, let $S$ be the surface of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the point $(0,1,0)$ removed.  Let $R \subset S$ be the closed annulus consisting of points $(x,y,z)$ of $S$ with $\lvert y \rvert \leq \frac{1}{2}$.  Then the complement of $R$ is an open disc on the bottom and a punctured open disc on the top, so it fulfills the requirements you've stated.

Now consider the map $R\rightarrow R$ that takes $(x,y,z)$ to $(x, -y, z)$.  This is a homeomorphism on the annulus, but it switches the boundary components.  In order to extend this to a homeomorphism of $S$, you would have to homeomorphically map the disc to the punctured disc and vice versa, which is impossible.

If you strengthen your assumptions, for example by assuming the homeomorphism of the subsurface preserves boundary components, then the answer becomes yes, and you can prove it using the Alexander trick as janmarqz suggests.  However, these extensions will not be unique, unless you start adding qualifiers like "up to isotopy".